# Is it bad to have a page with a lot of queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page with activities of users and their friends , like social network does with posts , likes, comments, and reshares  ... , which result with a lot of queries to show this page, sometimes 15 queries , and sometimes more...

Is this a bad thing ? because i'm trying to optimize a lot of things, but the number of queries still high... need your opinions

Comment: Consider loading the page with the minimum required data, and then adding additional data via Ajax requests.  That way the user doesn't have to wait through all of the queries before they see anything.

Comment: Also try eager loading to reduce the number of SQL queries

Comment: @JacobM add this as answer to add you a point, i appreciate any opinion, thank you :)

Comment: @arun15thmay i have already eager loaded a lot of association but still difficult to reduce the number of queries

Comment: Yes, a lot of queries is a bad thing. Ajax is an excellent way to reduce unecessary queries

Answer (score 1):

Slow responses to requests are bad, and lots of queries make for slow responses. But you can have your cake and eat it too with prudent use of caching. [Here's a guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) to caching in Rails, although you can also cache before the request gets to Rails, e.g. with [varnish](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

Comment: +1 thank you for this answer, but what is the role of caching before the request gets to Rails ?

Comment: @medBo, if the request is for something that can be served without hitting Rails then it can be served much faster, since it's then just a matter of checking the URL and expiration time, then serving the cached content as available. No Rails and no Ruby equals faster turnaround.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good idea to keep the number of database requests to a minimum, they tend to be slow. The database also tends to be the most difficult thing to scale so keeping the load down helps. You can reduce database calls by either rewriting your queries or (more likely) caching in your application or using HTTP caching.

An important thing to do before any of this though, is to define what level of performance you require. Depending on your load it could be that 15 queries is perfectly acceptable. It could also be possible that greater performance gains could be achieved by fixing something else in the code base.

Try to define your requirements, measure to find bottlenecks, then fix.